# Qt 5 c++ how to include a file when the path is masked by another path in INCLUDEPATH?

Tags: c++, linux, include, qt5, include-path

In my application, I'm trying to use my own build of ICU 54.1, on Mint 17.2 (which comes with ICU 52.1).  In my application's .pri I have:

```
  INCLUDEPATH += $${PWD}/third_party/icu/source/common \
                 $${PWD}/third_party/icu/source/i18n \
                 $${PWD}/third_party/build/icu/$${BUILD_MODE}/common

  LIBS += -L$${PWD}/third_party/build/icu/$${BUILD_MODE}/lib
  LIBS += $${PWD}/third_party/build/icu/$${BUILD_MODE}/lib/libicudata.so.54.1
  LIBS += $${PWD}/third_party/build/icu/$${BUILD_MODE}/lib/libicui18n.so.54.1
  LIBS += $${PWD}/third_party/build/icu/$${BUILD_MODE}/lib/libicuuc.so.54.1
```

In my application code, when I `#include <unicode/regex.h>` Qt Creator tooltip tells me it is using the unicode/regex.h in /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu, which is Mint's version, ICU 52.1.  But I want it to use the unicode/regex.h from ICU 54.1 that I built, which is in $${PWD}/third_party/icu/source/i18n.

Is there some way to set the preference of my ICU path over that of Mint's for includes?  What is the best-practice way to `#include` files from my build of ICU?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `#include <....>` it means include from standard location. Try to use `#include "......"` instead. I'm not sure but this may help.

Comment: I should have mentioned, I did try that.  No luck - the tooltip still shows it's using Mint's version of ICU.